# how to join three tables using primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

1. users
2. request_co
3. personal_service

I want to fetch records from these tables in MySQL database using joins.

With my code I can successfully access records from **`users`** and **`request_co`** using `**primary key`** of **`users`** table to **`request_co`** table.

But I am findig it difficult to access record of `personal_service` table where `primary key` of `users` table is placed in `personal_service`

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    users.*, request_co.*, personal_service.*
FROM
    users
        INNER JOIN
    request_co ON users.User_No = request_co.forwarded_user_id
        INNER JOIN
    personal_service ON users.User_No = personal_service.User_Id
WHERE
    status = 'APPROVED'
ORDER BY request_co.date DESC
```

How do I fetch records of `personal_service` table

DB Structure for users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `User_No` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `User_Name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_Password` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `User_Cnic` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_Rank` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_Unit` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_Appointment` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `Date_Time` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_Co_Name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_HOD_Name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_Role` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `User_Status` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `User_First_Run` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `User_Category` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `User_Picture` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`User_No`)
)
```

DB Structure for request_co table

```
CREATE TABLE `request_co` (
 `request_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `forwarded_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `forwarded_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `User_co` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `req_id_hod` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`request_id`),
 KEY `req_id_hod` (`req_id_hod`),
 CONSTRAINT `request_co_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`req_id_hod`) REFERENCES `request` (`request_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

DB Structure for personal_service table

```
CREATE TABLE `personal_service` (
 `Personal_Service_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Personal_Service_Rank` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `Personal_Service_No` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Service_Course` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Service_Branch` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Service_Unit` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Persoanl_Service_Status` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Service_Decorations` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Service_Filled` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Date` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `User_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Request_Id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Personal_Service_Id`),
 KEY `User_Id` (`User_Id`),
 CONSTRAINT `personal_service_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`User_Id`) REFERENCES `users` (`User_No`),
 CONSTRAINT `personal_service_print_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`User_Id`) REFERENCES `users` (`User_No`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: is there error or it returns nothing?

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: it would be good if u share design of your database table so that any one can easily understand your query

Comment: did you check `personal_service` and `users.status`

Comment: He said write it on post and make it look like more clean and solid :))

Comment: When sharing db structure just run the query `show create table table_name` then copy and paste as formatted text by editing your post.

Comment: Is forwarded_user_id is a foreign key of request_co table ?

Comment: yes  forwarded_user_id IS A FOREIGN KEY refers to users table

Comment: Why are there two constraints FK in table personal_service ? Also it would be ok if the User_id in Users table is int(11)... And finaly, I have to ask, if you remove this part: `WHERE
    status = 'APPROVED'` do you get any data back ? Thanks!

Comment: if i remove WHERE status = 'APPROVED' i t returns no record

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate that no rows match your conditions.  So, try `LEFT JOIN`s and see what is returned:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     request_co r
     ON u.User_No = r.forwarded_user_id AND
        r.status = 'APPROVED' LEFT JOIN
     personal_service ps
     ON u.User_No = ps.User_Id
ORDER BY r.date DESC
```

This might return what you want.  Or it might point out where your data does not meet your expectations so you can fix your query.